# Haskell - creating the sum of the ints in a list, if the ints are greater than 8

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to create the sum of a list, but only the numbers that are greater than 8.

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum[] = 0
sum (x:xs) | x > 8 = x
           | x < 8 = 0
sum (x:xs) = sum xs + x
          


main :: IO ()
main = do
print(sum [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

So I'd expect it to sum up 9-12 and give an output of 42, but instead it only gives 0.
If I remove the prerequisite then it functions as normal and sums the whole list, giving 78.
I've been trying for hours and still can't get any further than this, any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The last clause will only be triggered when `x` was *exactly* 8. So given the head of the list is smaller or greater than `8`, it will return `x` or `0` respectively, but never *recurse* on the rest of the list.

Comment: You've already made it recurse in the final line of the definition - the problem is that it only reaches that line if the first element is exactly 8. The solution is to remove the final line, change the first guard to `x <= 8`, and recourse in both cases, similarly to how you are currently doing it in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Your second clause does not *recurse*. It thus means that if `x > 8`, it will return `x`, and if `x < 8`, it will return `0`. Only in case `x` is exactly `8`, it will add `x` to the sum of the remaining elements, but this sum can easily terminate as well if the second element is not `8`.

You thus need to recurse in both scenarios where `x > 8`, or `x <= 8`:

```
sum8 :: [Int] -> Int
sum8 [] = 0
sum8 (x:xs) | x > 8 = x + sum xs
            | otherwise = sum xs
```

You however do not need explicit recursion for this. You can work with the builtin [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) function to sum elements, and [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) to filter the list of elements:

```
sum8 :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
sum8 = sum . filter (8 <)
```

or we can even generalize the function to work with all `Foldable` types with:

```
sum8 :: (Foldable f, Num a, Ord a) => f a -> a
sum8 = foldr f 0
    where f x | x > 8 = (x +)
              | otherwise = id
```

This will thus work on all sorts of `Foldable`s like lists (`[]`), [**`Tree`s**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Graph.html#t:Tree), [**`Maybe`s**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Maybe), etc.